# CCmake available variables

Tags: configuration, cmake

I want to set configuration variable (path, in particular) in CMakeList.txt for my project, which user can override in CCmake.
But if i just use 
`set(VAR <value>)`
`VAR` is not available for changing in CCMAKE, how can i do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add the `CACHE` part to your `set` command, it will be visible in CCMake.  So, e.g.

```
set(VAR <value> CACHE PATH "Some details about VAR")
```

The types of variable which appear in CCMake are `FILEPATH`, `PATH`, `STRING` and `BOOL`.

For full details, run:

```
cmake --help-command set
```

Comment: grep -E ':FILEPATH|:PATH|:STRING|:BOOL' CMakeCache.txt